# How can I make it so when the user inputs "n" times the program will stop?

Tags: java

I want to make it so when the user inputs a certain amount of times the program will terminate. How can I achieve this with my current code?

```
num = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Score for David");
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int count = 0;
int limit = num; 
while(true && count < num){
while(true){
   int check = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: When do you expect `while(true)` to end? Also, `while(true && count < num)` is the long-winded way of saying `while(count < num)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(count<10){
  stuff
  count++
}
```

or switch 10 for a number they input

Answer (score 0):

```
num = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Score for David");
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int count = 0;
int limit = num; 
while(count < num){
    int check = input.nextInt();
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, make sure your code is properly indented in the future to make it easier for the community to understand.

To make a loop (I'm assuming you will be using a while loop) that terminates after n iterations, implement the following code:

```
int x = 0;
while (x<n){
    x++;
    //this is where you add the rest of your code 
}
```